# Building a webapp around a accountent api

Tags: php, synchronization

I'm using a accounting software to store all my customers, and they have a big swagger like api. I can use the full crud features.
So i want to build a app that bassicly "extends" the accounting software, for example i can add a "hardware" or "key" field to a customer.

My idea right now is to make a app that loads all the customers and build all the crud features. So only the API. 
Then i want to save the custom fields in my own database connected to the id of a customer.

So lets say i click on "James" it will load its data from the api, and show my custom fields.

But i have the feeling this is not a good way to sync it..

So my question: Whats the best way to sync your php/sql webapp with a accounting api.

Comment: API is ambiguous.. Please tag it with a specific API

Comment: Let's say, swagger ui